# why am i getting compilation error "error: conflicting types for ‘ptr’ " for the following code? static int val=33; int *ptr;//=&val; ptr=&val;

Tags: c, pointers, static, int

My goal is to make a static variable 'val' available to a different .c file (just for experimentation) .

so i made a global pointer which holds the address of the static variable, and by this global pointer, i am trying to access the static variable's value in another file .

But,

```
static int val=33;
int *ptr;
ptr = &val;
```

gives me error.

while if i do it like this, it works .

```
static int val=33;
int *ptr = &val;
```

Why?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: It turns out this is an [mcve]. Putting the code shown in a file and compiling it with their compiler yields the message shown.

Comment: warning the meaning of the form `ptr = &val;` depends on where it is, look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doing

> ```
> static int val=33;
> int *ptr;
> ptr = &val; /* define a global variable with an init value */
> ```

at **global** scope you define global variables and for the compiler the implicit type of *ptr* is *int* in the line `ptr = &val;` so this is not compatible with an `int*`. You cannot have an assignment at global scope, this is why `ptr = &val;` is not the assignment of *ptr* previously defined but the definition of a global variable with an initial value.

Putting the code in a local scope there is no problem, for instance with

```
int main()
{
  static int val=33;
  int *ptr;
  ptr = &val; /* an assignment of ptr */
}
```

compile without problem

Comment: Putting the code in block scope defeats OP’s goal of providing the address in an external object. They should use their second code, initialization at file scope. Alternately, they can leave the declaration at file scope but put the assignment in block scope.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I added the second case to explain the same form can have different meaning depending on where it is, in the current case the difference between defining a global variable and assigning a local var ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old or poor quality compiler which assumes `int` for a missing type.

At file scope, an expression statement such as `ptr = &val;` is not part of standard C. The compiler is attempting to treat this as a declaration statement. To do that, it assumes a type of `int`, as if the statement were:

```
int ptr = &val;
```

Since `ptr` was previously declared `int *`, this new declaration with type `int` conflicts, and the compiler reports there are conflicting types.

C 2018 6.7.2 2 specifies a *constraint* for declarations:

> At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration, and in the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name.

When a constraint is violated, a compiler should issue a diagnostic message about it. So a good compiler will warn that the type specifier is missing (and not just that the resulting default type conflicts with a prior declaration).

Comment: is `gcc version 6.3.0` a poor  quality compiler ? ^^ (is the one I have under raspberrypi)

Comment: @bruno: It is old, and, without the right switches, it is poor quality. I recommend `-Wmost -std=c11` at a minimum, and `-Wpedantic` on top of that. But, even without switches, it warns: “warning: data definition has no type or storage class” and “warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'ptr'”.

Comment: It was mainly a joke, you preach a convinced, I use `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` when I compile, as you can see in my answers when I put the way to compiler ;-)